# MODx parser object is NULL

Tags: modx-revolution

**Fatal error: Call to a member function parseProperties() on a non-object in htdocs\core\model\modx\modelement.class.php on line 536**

Please help me fix this error, i tried on my own but failed. I am trying to run an existing project. I am completely new to MODx.

Comment: You might want to include some of your calling code otherwise no one will be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, i also think i should had done that; anyways, i fixed the error myself and it is working now. The problem was with path configuration for core which was resulting in parser object being NULL. Once i correctly configured it, i got the parser object. Anyways thanks for your attention, i will keep your advice in mind for future posts.

Comment: You can make this page more helpfull for your karma. Just add some details about where exactly you fixed path settings.

Answer (score 3):

This error appears sometimes after transferring site to another hosting. No need to patch system scripts, just clear the cache (remove core/cache/*).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is quite old but this worked for me...

Just commenting out the lines below in 
/core/cache/system_settings/config.cache.php around line number 370

```html
   /*'parser_class_path' => '/core/components/fastfield/model/fastfield/', 
'parser_class' => 'fastFieldParser',*/
```

Most likely components in the /core/components are missing and you need to re-download the missing components into that folder.

I am not quite sure what this translates to in English, but I found it here:
https://forums.modx.com/thread/86640/php-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-parseproperties